# determining level of n children in breadth first search

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

I am having trouble determining the level of the ending vertex in the breadth first search program. The program is below and any graph that I give it always returns the level of the vertex in the graph as 0.

I am guessing the problem is at the function "level" the function is below:

```
int level(int n,int v,int a[20][20])
{
    int i,j,k,count[20],le[20];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        count[i]=0;

    for(k=0;k < n;k++)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(count[i]==k)
                for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
                {
                    if(count[j]==0 && a[i][j]==1)
                        count[j]=k+1;
                    else 

                    count[j]=count[j];
                }
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        le[i]=count[i];

    return (*le);
}
```

I am trying to return the array le "level" with the level of each vertex and my vertices are numerically given.

My main function is below and it works fine and gives whether the graph is connected or not:

```
int main()
{
    int v,w,a[20][20],q[20],visited[20],n,i,j,count=0,le[20];
    printf("\n Enter the number of vertices:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        q[i]=0;
        visited[i]=0;
    }

    printf("\n Enter graph data in matrix form:\n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            printf("Is there an edge between (%d,%d)? ",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }

    printf("\n Enter the starting vertex:");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    printf("\n Enter the ending vertex:");
    scanf("%d",&w);

    bfs(v,a,q,visited,n);
    *le=level(n,v,a);
    count=le[w];

    if(visited[w]==1)
        printf("\nBfs is possible at %d level\n",count);
    else
        printf("\n Bfs is not possible\n");
}
```

I have returned the array as a pointer . that is fine right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `le` as int `le[20]` and return `*le`. This will return the first value of the array. But the first value of `le` and `buffer` is never set in level.

The content of the array `le` is not returned. So when you do `count= le[w]` in `main`, you get what was in `le` before the call of `level`.

Pass `le` as argument to `level` like you did for `a`.

There is also this `count[j] = count[j];` instruction in `level`. This instruction does nothing. Are you sure this is what you wanted to do ?

In C, arrays are indexed from 0 to n-1. You use the range from 1 to n. It is error prone. For instance the array element `buffer[0]` is not initialized or set. You should stick to the 0 to n-1 range.

Comment: thanks a lot! its done after deleting count instruction and passing le

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your code, But what's the point of

```
count[j]=count[j];
```

? Can you check that ?